# Counting bigram frequencies in python

Tags: python

Assume that i have a data that looks like

```
['<s>', 'I' , '<s>', 'I', 'UNK', '</s>']
```

I would like to get the number of bigram that occurs only once, so

```
n1 == ('I', '<s>'), ('I', 'UNK'), ('UNK', '</s>')
len(n1) == 3
```

and number of bigram that occurs twice

```
n2 == ('<s>', 'I')
len(n2) == 1
```

I am thinking of storing the first word as sen[i] and the next word as sen[i + 1] but I am not sure if this is the right approach.

Comment: do you have this format or you can convert it to list format ?

Comment: nltk has a nice FreqDist function that should be pretty useful for this.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [counting n-gram frequency in python nltk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14364762/counting-n-gram-frequency-in-python-nltk)

Comment: That first line isn't valid python.  Is it supposed to be a string?  A list of strings?  Something else?  Please correct.

Comment: @altendky Sorry. It should loop over a list of list of strings (corpus)

Comment: @Alibaba17 I'll assume you mean a list of strings given what's there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Considering your list:-

```
lis = ['<s>', 'I' , '<s>', 'I', 'UNK', '</s>']
```

loop over the list to generate the tuples of bigrams and keep getting their frequency into the dictionary like this:-

```
bigram_freq = {}
length = len(lis)
for i in range(length-1):
    bigram = (lis[i], lis[i+1])
    if bigram not in bigram_freq:
        bigram_freq[bigram] = 0
    bigram_freq[bigram] += 1
```

Now, collect the bigrams with frequency = 1 and frequency = 2 like this:-

```
bigrams_with_frequency_one = 0
bigrams_with_frequency_two = 0
for bigram in bigram_freq:
    if bigram_freq[bigram] == 1:
        bigrams_with_frequency_one += 1
    elif bigram_freq[bigram] == 2:
        bigrams_with_frequency_two += 1
```

you have bigrams_with_frequency_one and bigrams_with_frequency_two as your results.
I hope it helps!

Comment: So, we just return the length of bigrams_with_frequency_one = []
bigrams_with_frequency_two = [] to get the frequency right?

Comment: Oh sorry, My bad... I did not notice. It was even easier than what I did....I am editing. Please accept my answer if it is useful. :)

Comment: It was really helpful. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
my_list = ['<s>', 'I' , '<s>', 'I', 'UNK', '</s>']

bigrams = [(l[i-1], l[i]) for i in range(1, len(my_list))]
print(bigrams)
# [('<s>', 'I'), ('I', '<s>'), ('<s>', 'I'), ('I', 'UNK'), ('UNK', '</s>')]

d = {}

for c in set(bigrams):
    count = bigrams.count(c)
    d.setdefault(count, []).append(c)

print(d)
# {1: [('I', '<s>'), ('UNK', '</s>'), ('I', 'UNK')], 2: [('<s>', 'I')]}
```